# Data normalization of different data ranges in R with reduced data loss

Tags: r, normalization

I have a `data.frame` with columns that contains data in different ranges. For example, below is the max and min values for these columns:

```
    Column1      Column2  Column3 Column4 Column5
max 0.35447      1.341088 1       1       0.04414619
min 2.640912e-41 0        0       0       8.776936e-08
```

What I would like to do is to normalize all columns between the same range `[0, 1]` with just thousandths decimals. I know that this will probably result in information loss, specially for data in Column 1 and Column 5. There is a way to reduce the data loss for these columns?

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: What do you mean by data loss?  Do you mean you will have to drop the variables?  Or do you mean "information loss" where you will have to round them down.

Comment: Hey @mandata thanks for the question. I edited my question and changed from data loss to information loss :)

Comment: actually I meant drop the data points, but my point got across, and was not lost. ;)